# Dataflow worker pool creation and deletion time overhead

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In the execution of each Dataflow job, job is taking around 2-4 mins for the creation and deletion of VMs(worker pool).
Please let me know if there is any way to minimize this?
OR
Can we create VMs for processing before execution of Dataflow job so that execution time can bring down?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to minimize the provisioning and deletion of Compute Engine instances; this is all done automatically by the Dataflow service. Additionally, I don't think there's a way to specify Dataflow to use existing Compute Engine instances. Is the overhead time a significant blocker for you?

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow is fully managed. From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#workers):

> You should not attempt to manage or otherwise interact directly with
>   your [Compute Engine Managed Instance Group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/); the Dataflow service will
>   take care of that for you. Manually altering any Compute Engine
>   resources associated with your Dataflow job is an unsupported
>   operation.